# Magento 2.1.1 upgrade issue

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.1

I upgraded my 2.1.0 store from the Admin and the console stated it completed successfully. However my Admin and frontend are now displaying the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException' with message 'The file "/home/extende/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Theme/Model/ResourceModel/Design/Config/CollectionFactory.php" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/home/extende/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Theme/Model/ResourceModel/Design/Config/CollectionFactory.php): Permission denied' in /home/extende/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382 Stack trace: #0 /home/extende/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(405): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/home/extende/p...') #1 /home/extende/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/home/extende/p...') #2 /home/extende/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/home/extende/p...') #3 /home/extende/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesy in /home/extende/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php on line 382

Comment: Have you try update your file permission? From the error message, I think it worth a try.

Comment: You cannot change the permissions of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the composer way to install and upgrade Magento 2. It seems to be a problem with di:compile.

Go to your console and do the following:

```
rm -Rf vendor
rm -Rf pub/static/*
rm -Rf var/generation/*
rm -Rf var/cache/*
composer install
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

These commands will delete every generic data and compile them again. If there were any problems while updating magento, you will see them while downloading your dependencies via composer.

Please be careful with the rm -Rf commands and never delete any .htaccess-File.

Hope this will help.

Comment: When I execute the command bin/magento setup:upgrade it says "Permission denied" ?

Comment: So that means that you dont have permissions. Are you sudo on your system? Try sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I am not on sudo. I have had a look at update.log  and found errors: [2016-08-31 07:44:03] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:  /home/extende/public_html/.htaccess

Comment: What kind of setup do you have? You need to be sudo to install, update and maintain Magento 2 correctly.

Comment: Usually I use the command bin/magento setup:upgrade and it works fine.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade worked

Comment: The menus System, Stores, Reports etc in the left hand column of the Admin no longer open up when you click on them and product images do not load in the frontend?